# como fazer um programa no qual se digita um valor monetário e seja exibida na tela a quantidade de cédulas e moedas de cada tipo serão utilizadas

Tags: c

Olá, estou tentando realizar um programa no qual, você tem que pedir para o usúario digitar uma valor monetário( aleatório ) e deixar ser exibido na tela a quantidade de cédulas e moedas de cada tipo juntas totalizam esse valor.
Porém, cada cédula, tem uma restrição de quantidade. Por exemplo: 4 notas de 200,00.
2 de 100,00

Eu estou tentando a dias, mas não consigo entender o que está dando de errado, está ficando algo enorme,e além disso, acredito que estou colocando algo fora de ordem.  esse é o meu código por enquanto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float centavos;
    int valor, ced200, ced100, ced50, ced20, ced10, ced5, ced2, ced1, moe050, moe025, moe010, moe005, moe001;
    ced200 = 0;
    ced100 = 0;
    ced50 = 0;
    ced20 = 0;
    ced10 = 0;
    ced5 = 0;
    ced2 = 0;
    ced1 = 0;
    moe050 = 0;
    moe025 = 0;
    moe010 = 0;
    moe005 = 0;
    moe001 = 0;



    printf(" Digite um valor monetario:");
    scanf( "%d" , &valor );
    printf(" Digite um valor para moedas:");
    scanf( "%f" , &centavos );

    while( valor >= 200 );
    {
         ced200 = +1;
         valor = valor - 200;
    }
    while( valor >= 100 )
    {
         ced100 = +1;
         valor = valor - 100;
    }
    while( valor >= 50 )
    {
         ced50 = +1;
         valor = valor - 50;
    }
    while( valor >= 20 )
    {
         ced20 = +1;
         valor = valor - 20;
    }
    while( valor >= 10 )
    {
         ced10 = +1;
         valor = valor - 10;
    }
    while( valor >= 5 )
    {
         ced5 = +1;
         valor = valor - 5;
    }
    while( valor >= 2 )
    {
         ced2 = +1;
         valor = valor - 2;
    }
    while( valor >= 1 )
    {
         ced1 = +1;
         valor = valor - 1;
    }
    while( centavos >= 0.50 )
    {
         moe050 = +1;
         centavos = centavos - 0.50;
    }
    while( centavos >= 0.25 )
    {
         moe025 = +1;
         centavos = centavos - 0.25;
    }
    while( centavos >= 0.10 )
    {
         moe010 = +1;
         centavos = centavos - 0.10;
    }
    while( centavos >= 0.05 )
    {
         moe005 = +1;
         centavos = centavos - 0.05;
    }
    while( centavos >= 0.01 )
    {
         moe001 = +1;
         centavos = centavos - 0.01;
    }
    
    if ( ced200 > 4)
    {
        printf(" não existe notas suficientes");
    }
    else if ( ced100 > 2)
    {
        printf(" não existe notas suficientes");
    }
    else if ( ced50 > 3)
    {
        printf(" não existe notas suficientes");
    }
    else if ( ced20 > 3)
    {
        printf(" não existe notas suficientes");
    }
    else if ( ced10 > 4)
    {
        printf(" não existe notas suficientes");
    }
    else if ( ced5 > 2)
    {
        printf(" não existe notas suficientes");
    }
    else if ( ced2 > 3)
    {
        printf(" não existe notas suficientes");
    }
    else if ( ced1 > 5)
    {
        printf(" não existe notas suficientes");
    }
    else if ( moe050 > 6)
    {
        printf(" não existe moedas suficientes");
    }
    else if ( moe025 > 4)
    {
        printf(" não existe moedas suficientes");
    }
    else if ( moe010 > 3)
    {
        printf(" não existe moedas suficientes");
    }
    else if ( moe005 > 8)
    {
        printf(" não existe moedas suficientes");
    }
    else if ( moe001 > 7)
    {
        printf(" não existe moedas suficientes");
    }

    else
    {
        printf(" Nao e possivel formar esse valor com as cedulas e moedas disponiveis ");
    }
    printf("A quantidade de notas de 200 é:",ced200,"ced100 é",ced100,"ced50 é",ced50,"ced20 é",ced20,"ced10 é",ced10,"ced5 é",ced5,"ced2 é",ced2,"ced1 é",ced1,"moe050",moe050,"moe025",moe025,"moe010",moe010,"moe005",moe005,"moe001",moe001);


    return 0;
}
```

Onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar arrays? Certamente seu código ficará muito mais compacto.

Comment: Avalie a utilização do operador `%` (resto da divisão) que você eliminará este monte de `while`s. Note que você declarou seu valor como inteiro e portanto seu valor não poderá conter a parte decimal (os centavos). Aliás em C o separador decimal é `.` e não `,`. Talvez fique mais fácil para os cálculos você multiplicar os valores por 100 e trabalhar apenas com inteiros. Continua valendo o comentário anterior.